# Can't Post in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have node js(expressjs) web site. In this website I can sign in or sign up.
For example:

```
router.get("/signin", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signin");
});
```

And:

```
router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('login', {
    succsessRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signin',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Also I have sign up code.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var age = req.body.age;

    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            req.flash('error', 'User already exists');
            return res.redirect('/signup');
        }

        var newUser = new User({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            fname: fname,
            age: age
        });
        newUser.save(next);
    });
}, passport.authenticate('login', {
    succsessRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Everything working fine, so when I try to sign up, my website sign me up in database( I use mongoDB and passport js third-party middleware) but when passport should redirect me to the main page "/" it doesn't
and appears error "Can not POST /signup". This problem happens with sign in too. What can you suggest me to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change your code

```
newUser.save(next);
```

to something like

```
newUser.save(function(err, newUser){return res.redirect('/');});
```

Comment: It doesn't help :(